# Jquery .on() not triggering toggleClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dynamically adding a column on click to a table with a similar class name with JS/Jquery as show below

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('#week_title').append('<th>Week '+count+'</th>');
    count++;
    $('.tag').append('<td class="highlight"><img src="plus.png"></td>');
});
```

Then once a column is dynamically added, on click on each cell I have a toggleClass() function to switch a css add_week_bg class function to display it being marked as show below

```
$(".highlight").on("click", function(){
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass("add_bg");
});
```

My issue comes in to play once the a column has been dynamically added, and when that cell is clicked the .on() doesn't trigger.

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aqW6a/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: because `on()` does not magically bind itself to new elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need event delegation (*as .highlight being added dynamically*)

```
$('.tag').on("click",".highlight", function(){
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass("add_bg");
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/aqW6a/1/

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Wow many thanks for the quick response. Will accept when I am able too.

Answer (score 0):

Try  http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('.tag').on("click", ".highlight",function(){
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass("add_bg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a selector problem, you should operate over a generic selector

```
$(document).on("click",".highlight", function(){
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass("add_bg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event Delegation

```
$(".tag").on("click",'.highlight', function () {
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass("add_bg");
});
```